# Multithreaded bitmap access in android

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, synchronization

I have an app which repeatedly draws a bitmap on the screen.  Meanwhile I have occasional updates to the bitmap.  Currently I draw them on the bitmap in the ui thread, in between screen updates.  I would like to move this drawing to a background thread.  So I will be simultaneously reading from and writing to the bitmap's bits.   Is it safe to do this in android without protecting the bitmap with the synchronized keyword?

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe. You have to protect your bitmap as long as it is shared. You should trigger UI refresh when the bitmap operation is finished. don't write and read the bitmap simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks!  Is that based on general principles, or have you tried it and run into problems, or do you have specific knowledge of the relevant code?

Comment: I suggest you can download and read Android Gallery source code. It's helpful. I learned how to process bitmap appropriately from that.